# Microsoft Teams web-hook return respond 404 for Adaptive Card

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I was trying to send data to Microsoft Teams with a valid webhook my code is below

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://webhooks.valid_url.com/WebhookHandler/test"

payload = json.dumps({
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "contentUrl": None,
      "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.2",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "For Samples and Templates, see [https://adaptivecards.io/samples](https://adaptivecards.io/samples)"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.status_code)
```

I follow this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook) to write this code but each time I try to send data it returns 404 where the webhook URL is valid.

If I update the payload to this it sends the message perfectly.

```
payload = {
    "text": "Hello, this is a message sent to Teams from Python!",
}
```

As my investigation pure text message is sent but If I try to add any extra design it returns 404. So my question is what I am missing when the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card) says Adaptive Card is valid and when I try to use their code it returns 404?

Comment: Did you try sending the same card using webhook via Postman? We did try that and it was getting sent properly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CywvE.png

Comment: Yes, I tried it with Postman but I got 404 as a return. But your image made me confused with my webhook. If you get replay for the same code why I'm getting 404 ?

Comment: What error does it show? 404- webhook URL is invalid